# WSO2 Admin Secondary User Store - Delete Icon is not Working

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-identity-server

For test purpose I added a read-only LDAP look-up via the User Store Management menu at admin, selecting the option:

org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager

After testing, I'm not able to remove this store entry at the Web console doing a "Select All" and selecting the the "Delete" icon. The command confirms deletion of the store, but after a new lookup the entry is still present. It is currently set in a disabled state, as some details are yet missing in the LDAP setup.

It displays a pop-up message like this:
Do you want to delete the selected user stores? Yes 
Selected user stores are being deleted. Refresh the page after few seconds to check the new status. OK

After this issue, the dashboard login function stopped working, not accepting local LDAP store registered users. Under admin console access, the local users are still visible.

Please advice how to correct this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A "kill -9 process number" solved the problem reported above and new start of the Identity server removed the web cache error. Yes, it did remove all the persistent entries.

Comment: I've removed a section of your answer that was a question: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.