# WSO2 Identity Server - Adding a Corporate LDAP as Secondary User Store - Field Layout Mapping?

Tags: ldap, wso2, identity

I like to request an advice about the configuration options in the WSO2 Identity Server to adjust the layout of a corporate LDAP directory and reuse it as a Secondary Read Only User store in the IdP. Is there a mapping function available that correlates the WSO2 field terminology to the context of the corporate directory, mapping the mandatory WSO2 identity fields like [ First Name, Last Name, Address, Phone Number and others]?

This question is complementary to my previous question about the access locking.
[WSO2 Admin Secondary User Store - Delete Icon is not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003897/wso2-admin-secondary-user-store-delete-icon-is-not-working/30063633#30063633)

Thanks in advance for your advice how to integrate an external LDAP repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use claim management in WSO2 identity server. In the Identity Server, each user store attribute can be mapped as a claim. Therefore, you can use the claim management functionality available in the Identity Server and properly map your LDAP/AD/JDBC user store attributes with the claim URIs defined by the Identity Server. You can also add different claim URIs and manage them using claim management.

Please refer the below links to find how to do user attribute mapping.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Managing+User+Attributes

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Adding+New+Claim+mapping

You can add your corporate LDAP directory as secondary user store.
You can follow the below steps to configure secondary user stores manually or using the management console:

configure the [IS_HOME]\repository\conf\user-mgt.xml file as given below.

Using management console:

Log in to the management console and click User Store Management sub menu under Configure menu.
List item
The User Store Management page opens
Click Add Secondary User Store.
In the User Store Manager Class list, select the type of user store you are creating (in here u can populate this drop-down list with custom user store manager implementations by adding them to the server.)
Enter a unique domain name with no underscore (_) characters, and optionally enter a description for this user store.
Enter values for the properties, using the descriptions in the Descriptions column for guidance. The properties that appear vary based on the user store manager class you selected, and there may be additional properties in an Optional or Advanced section at the bottom of the screen.
Ensure that all the mandatory fields are filled and a valid domain name is given and click Add.
A message appears saying that the user stores are being added. (The message does not imply that the user store is added successfully. It simply means that the server is attempting to add the new user store to the end of the available chain of stores.)
Refresh the page after a few seconds to check the status.
If the new user store is successfully added, it will appear in the User Store Management page.
After adding to the server, you can edit the properties of the new secondary user store and enable/disable it in a dynamic manner.
Using manually:

You can find the primary user store configuration in [IS_HOME]\repository\conf\ the user-mgt.xml file. When you create a secondary user store using the management console, its configuration is saved to an XML file with the same name as the domain name you specify. Alternatively, you can create this XML file manually and save it as follows:

When you configure multiple user stores, you must give a unique domain name to each user store in the `<domainname>` element. If you configure a user store without specifying a domain name, the server throws an exception at start up.

If it is the configuration of a super tenant, save the secondary user store definitions in <product_home>/repository/deployment/server/userstores directory.
If it is a general tenant, save the configuration in <product_home>/repository/tenants/<tenantid>/userstores directory.
The secondary user store configuration file must have the same name as the domain with an underscore (_) in place of the period. For example, if the domain is wso2.com, name the file as wso2_com.xml.
One file only contains the definition for one user store domain.
You can follow the below steps:

Comment: Your answer contains unwanted details.